# How to add border to a TABLE or DIV in html email in Hotmail?

Tags: html, css, email, hotmail

Yes, html emails are bad but I have to send `html newsletter` to my a list of clients. Most of them use `Hotmail`.

Is it possible to add a `CSS` border around a `<table>` / `<div>` element?

`<div style="border:1px solid #000000;">BORDER</div>` doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;">Hola</div>
```

if it works

Comment: Try <div style="border:1px solid #000;">Hola</div>

Answer (score 11):

Looks like the best option is creating a table within a table:

```
<table bgcolor="#ACD13C" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"><tr>
                                            <td><table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                               <tr>
                                                 <td style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 0.9em; color: #000000; font-family: Arial,helvetica,sans; padding:0px; text-align:left;" width="400">Text goes here</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table></td></tr></table>
```

Hotmail just doesn't like borders...

Answer (score 8):

try to use

```
border="1"
```

Comment: `<table border="1">`  works for me in Outlook (desktop application) and is the solution with the lowest number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid specifying for a generic name like "black" or a shortened version of the hex color (like "#000", which does not always work) is to specify each element seperately like so:

```
<table style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#000000;"><tr><td>....</td></tr></table>
```